# Scanner to prompt user for numbers

Tags: java

Here are the instructions I'm trying to follow:

> Write a method called negative sum that accepts a scanner reading
>   input from a file containing a series of integers., and a print
>   message to the console indicating whether the sum starting from the
>   first number is ever negative.You should alse return true if a
>   negative sum can be reached and false if not. for example, suppose the
>   file contains the 38 4 19 -27 -15 -3 4 19 38 your  method would
>   consider the sum of just number (38) , the first two numbers  ( 38 +
>   4)  the firs three number ( 38 + 4 + 19) and so on to the asnd . none
>   of thes sume is negative so the method would produce the following
>   output and return false : No negative numbers.
>
> If the file instead contains 14 7 -10 9 -18 -10 17 42 98 the method
>   finds that a negative sum of -8 is reached after adding the first six
>   numbers. it should output the following to the console and return
>   true: sum of -8 after 6 steps.

This is what I have so far.  I'm just having trouble adding the scanner to prompt the user for the numbers.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NegativeSum{
    public static void main (String [] args )
    throws FileNotFoundException{


        negativesum();


        }//end of amin

public static boolean negativesum()
throws FileNotFoundException{


     File file = new File ("negativeSum.txt");
    Scanner input =  new Scanner (file);

    int sum=0;
    int count = 0;

    while ( input.hasNextInt()){
        int next =input.nextInt();
        sum+=next;
        count++;

        if ( sum<0){
            System.out.println("sum of " + sum + " after " + count + "steps" );
            return true;
            }

        }///end of while
    System.out.println("no negative sum ");
    return false;




    }//end of metho d

}//end of main
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about needing human input. However, if you do need human input, you simply create a Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) and then call in.next() to prompt the user. Check out the [Scanner documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for specifics on reading different value types.

Comment: You are reading the input from file then why do you need to prompt user for input

Comment: that file is what is confusing me . ! i don't even know what it suppose to be in the file? i just saved my code as txt file. and i don't think is right !

Comment: They just want you to use a file full of numbers, with either spaces or newlines in between.

Answer (score 1):

The only serious mistake I see in your implementation (vs. your problem statement) is that your method should receive a `Scanner` as input (e.g. *accepts a scanner*) -

```
public static boolean negativeSum(Scanner input) {
  if (input == null) {
    // Handle null - e.g. no value
    return false;
  }
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;

  while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    int next = input.nextInt();
    sum += next;
    count++;

    if (sum < 0) {
      System.out.println("sum of " + sum + " after "
          + count + " steps");
      return true;
    }
  }// /end of while
  System.out.println("no negative sum");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: One nice thing about this solution is that you can _either_ call `negativeSum(new Scanner(new File("negativeSum.txt")));` in your `main` method, _or_ you can call `negativeSum(new Scanner(System.in));` if you want the user to type some numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your problem description that asks you to prompt the user for numbers. It appears that your code already meets the stated requirements of the assignment.

If you did want to do that, though:

- [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) is an `InputStream` representing standard input.
- The [`Scanner(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream%29) constructor creates a `Scanner` that reads from the specified `InputStream`.

I'll leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how to put the two together. :)

Comment: @DavidWallace Ha, I didn't even *see* your comment.

Comment: In that case, ignore my other comment too!